# Sending automated emails based on form response and timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script

I have set up a google form which links to a google sheet. Column 1 is a timestamp of when the respondent submitted the form. Column 2 is the respondents email address. Columns 3 and 4 is additional data that is being collected. Finally, column 5 is a yes/no/"Not Sure" response

I would like to have google send an automated message 2 weeks from the timestamp date (currently in the following format - 8/7/2019 16:36:02) for those that respond "Not Sure" in column 5. I would only like the script to send the email on new responses. The email is essentially a follow up to see if the "Not Sure" has changed to a yes/no, so only one email is needed.

I have seen scripts for automated emails via google but the issue is that the data needs to take a certain form that they have specified. Here is the script I found:

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to script an automated message with the format my data is in rather than the data the script specifies? - *edited*  I realized my sheet is in fact structured, just not in the same way the script is set up.

Here is the link to my sheet- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tSaDdmlvhNElTO4aIJCdGpbNnqmhFYE1Hrv0jSJ2W3Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about `there a way to script an automated message without having to structure the google sheet columns to a specific format`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve]. And Please provide an example of your unstructured Google Sheet.

Comment: Thank you both for flagging. I used unstructured improperly. My sheet is not structured in the same way that the script is designed for. This is a result of how the google form that collects the data is formatted. 

Is it possible to modify the script so that it reflects the formatting of my google sheet?

I have included the link to the google sheet, as well as the script that I found for automated emails.

Comment: Thank you for updating it. Unfortunately, from your updated question, I cannot still understand about your goal. Can you provide the sample result (format of message) you want? By this, I would like to try to think of the issue and solution. By the way, your current script in your question is different from the script in the shared Spreadsheet? How about this?

Comment: I have typed out a draft message in the tab labeled "automated reply" in cell a1. My desired outcome is that when a new entry appears in the sheet, an automated email should go out 2 weeks from the date provided in the timestamp column to the recipient in the email column IF and only if the response in the "do you plan to respond column" (e) is "Not Sure"

I have also reconciled the script that is in the sheet.